# Why won't After Effects import an uncompressed avi file?

Tags: after-effects, codec, adobe, adobe-media-encoder

I just recorded a demo from cod4 with 2000FPS.

I used Vdub to make an uncompressed video from the Screenshots. 
After saving as an avi, the file looks good. (Apart from the lack while playing in windows media player which is probably caused by the large Framerate)

When I try to import to after effects or encoder, I get the error that it can't be imported.

But why?

Comment: Please, add an error message, which you are facing. Also, you can make video from screenshots inside AE, and you will not face that error.

Comment: @Shultc yeah but when i import a sequence, it will also be interpreted as a 25fps footage. But I recorded with avidemo at 2000fps

Comment: It should not do like that. Check your composition settings.

Comment: In any case, the max composition frame rate in AE is 99 fps, unless you use a particular trick - see https://www.reddit.com/r/AfterEffects/comments/379wsd/importing_footage_over_99fps/.

Comment: @Mulvya yh, nice fix, but I cant even get my footage into after effects

Comment: Why not try to import the screenshots as image sequence?

Comment: @yes I already tried it and it works, I can than tell ae how to treat the footage, with how many fps and stuff. Problem is, the Sequence consists of, well as I mentioned before, 2000 .tga images. Something I can't really work with. But I will import the sequence to ae, and make it a 60fps footage, render as compresse video and than work with that in the project. I can than time warp the footage too it's original speed and If I have to, I can slow down and have super awesome slowmotion

Comment: @SlimMarten wasn't notified. It's good practice use a **proxy sequence** to work with. Import your tga's and render it as compressed jpg's, work with it and **replace the footage when you're done.

Comment: What's the video codec? AVI is a container, it's possible that the AVI contains a codec that Premiere doesn't know about. You can check the codec in VLC.

Answer (score 1):

After effects should take in the image sequence just fine. No reason to run it through Vdub first. Let me know how it works out for you, it sounds like a very interesting project.

Answer (score 0):

Given that the frame rate is extremely high, I'm assuming you want to slow it down later?  Nothing you ever watch on TV or in the Cinema is played back at that speed - the most you'd ever need is 50fps playback.  Usually 25fps in Europe, or 29.97 / 30 fps in the US.

You don't say what COD4 is - I'm assuming it's Call of Duty - the computer game?  Your video card probably runs at a max of 60fps, so 2000fps is probably massively high.

Either way, I would try converting the individual frames into image files first, [using VirtualDub](http://www.virtualdub.org/blog/pivot/entry.php?id=34).

Then once you have them as an image sequence, you can import them into AE at any playback frame rate you want.  (I suspect you might want to throw away some unnecessary frames).

Comment: How can you say what framerate he needs? the human eye can detect differences in very high framerates--if the display device supports it.

Comment: I didn't say what frame rate he needs. I pointed out what normal broadcasting frame rates are. When you're trying to learn to use a piece of software with lots of variables, it's helpful to have a sense of what the normal ranges are.

Comment: GPUs often render much more than the 60 frames most displays show. I'm not sure however, if it's possible to "get" those frames if they*re never sent to the display. I'd be very interested to hear from OP what effective refresh rate he gets on average.